# Add Additional Jpabnel

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel

I have to Add some points in my following GUI. Following is the Code i have done so far

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class PoiS extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
     JPanel p;
     JButton bplus, bminus;
     double factor = 0.5;
     JPanel titlePanel;
     JLabel redLabel;
     PoiS(){
         p = new DrawingPanel();
         /*
            buttonMinus = new JButton("Zoom In");
        buttonPlus = new JButton(" Zoom Out ");
        buttonMinus.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPlus.addActionListener(this);
        Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        box.add(buttonMinus);
        box.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        box.add(buttonPlus);
        box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        add(box, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

          */ 
         //Here i was creating a new Panel To enter to my Original panel P
         titlePanel = new JPanel();
         titlePanel.setLayout(null);
         titlePanel.setLocation(10, 0);
         titlePanel.setSize(250, 30);
         p.add(titlePanel);
 /*
         redLabel = new JLabel("Red Team");
         redLabel.setLocation(0, 0);
         redLabel.setSize(120, 30);
         redLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
         redLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
         titlePanel.add(redLabel);*/

         bplus = new JButton("+");
         bminus = new JButton("-");
         bplus.addActionListener(this);
         bminus.addActionListener(this);
         Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
         box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
         box.add(bminus);
         box.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
         box.add(bplus);
         box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
         add(box, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

         //add(new JLabel("\n"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
         //add(new JLabel("  subash   "),BorderLayout.EAST);
         //add(new JLabel("   kafley  "),BorderLayout.WEST);
         JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
         lbl.setText("Hotel1");

         //lbl.setText("hotel1");
         lbl.setLocation(20,20);
         lbl.setVisible(true);

         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setSize(600,400);
         setVisible(true);





     }

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == bplus) {
            factor += 0.1;
        }
        else {
            factor -= 0.1;
        }
        bminus.setEnabled(factor > 0.1);
        bplus.setEnabled(factor < 4.0);
        p.repaint();
            JLabel redLabel = new JLabel("Red Team");
            redLabel.setLocation(0, 0);
            redLabel.setSize(120, 30);
            redLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
            redLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
            //redLabel.setVisible(true);
            redLabel.add(p);
            //redLabel.setVisible(true);



    }
     public static void main(String []arg) {
        /* File file = new  i was trying to get my x axis and y axis from the txt file  File("/Users/kafley/Documents/Studymaterial/ITC313/Assignment1/src/Points.txt");
         FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
         String line;
         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
             String[] record = line.split(",\\s*");
             for(int i=0;i<record.length; i++){
                 System.out.print(record[i]);*/






         /*String line;
         try {
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/kafley/Documents/Studymaterial/ITC313/Assignment1/src/Points.txt"));
          while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
             System.out.println(line);
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }*/
       PoiS print = new PoiS();
       JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
       lbl.setText("Hotel1");
       lbl.setLocation(20, 20);
       lbl.setVisible(true);



     }
 }
```

> ```
> and another class
> ```

```
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;

 /**
  *
  * @author kafley
  */
 class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        double squareSize[] = {100.0, 50.0};
            double factor = 0.5;
        DrawingPanel() {
    super(null);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        }

            @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Dimension dim = this.getSize();
            int width = dim.width - 10;
            int height = dim.height - 10;
            for(int i = 0; i < squareSize.length; ++i) {
                int squareWidth = (int) (squareSize[i] * factor);
                int x = (width - squareWidth) / 2;
                int y = (height - squareWidth) / 2;
                g.drawRect(x, y, squareWidth, squareWidth);
            }
                 }
 }
```

Just Ignore Those Comment Parts as  copy paste from my Netbeans

I didn't want to delete because I thougt I might need it in future. I just want you to help me to plot another JPanel in this Frame. Any help will be Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure... but is this ok?:

```
redLabel.add(p);// <- redLabel is JLabel,and p is JPanel...?
```

If I've understood the problem... you should also add redLabel to some panel.